# Ошибки при сборке драйвера MySQL 8.0.19-winx64 и QT 5.14.1

Tags: mysql, qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]MySQL 8.0.19-winx64
mingw73_64
Qt 5.14.1
Делаю так:

1). В консоли C:\Qt\5.14.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers> qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\mysql\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\mysql\lib"

2). Выводит ошибки -

```
`g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++1z'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshift-overflow=2'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Makefile:838: .obj/qsql_sqlite.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/5.14.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:50: sub-sqlite-make_first] Error 2`
```

Что делаю не так и как это исправить?

На https://forum.qt.io/ прочитал, что возможно это связано с некорректной версией MinGW компилятора. Моя версия -

```
 `C:\Users\User>gcc --version
gcc (i686-posix-sjlj, built by strawberryperl.com project) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`
```

Что странно, ведь Qt ставил с mingw 7.3.0. Как обновить версию на более новую?

Comment: На скриншоте gcc 7.3

Comment: По крайней мере должен быть. Укажите компилятор через переменную с полным путем

Comment: @eri спасибо за вариант, я что то затупил, даже не подумал указать полный путь. Я пошел более долгим путем - удалил все gcc, и пути в path оставил только один, все пошло)

Answer (score 0):

Все, проблема решена. Я качал себе новые gcc, ставил их, но в cmd уверенно отображалась старая версия, какие бы я не ставил. Потом поиском нашел все gcc, оказывается у меня они еще в 2 папках были, удалил лишние, удалил пути в path ко всем старым gcc. После этого в консоли наконец начал отображаться правильный gcc